# Windows XP Connecting to And Logging a Computer Out Remotely

Tags: windows, permissions, logging, remote-control

How can I securely connect to a Windows XP machine and then cause the current user to be logged out?

I only need console access for the remote connection and could use non-MS software.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this with logmein.com

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly:  If you are running WinXP Pro on the host, you should be able to setup Remote Desktop.  Then use RDP client on the remote.  Since XP is a client software, it doesn't support concurrent users - when you RDP to the host, the current session automatically terminates.  Note that when the remote session logs in, it shows up on the host machine - a local use could mistakenly believe that they are the only session in use and try to type/use the mouse...  I don't know of any way to lock out the host user.  Other remote access software often have a way to put up a screen or blank out the host screen and ignore the mouse/keyboard, but don't know that RDP has.  But... RDP is free for XP Pro.

As for XP Home, yeah, you have to go with a third party software.

Comment: when you connect to an XP Pro machine via rdp, the local session is locked so that a local user would have to hit ctrl+alt+del and enter a password to unlock and use the PC. This would also disconnect the rdp session.